# Git. How to save changes in wrong branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in my git project( Let it be branch A and B). I made some changes in branch A, but I need it in B, not A. How I can switch to other branch? When I try "git checkout B" git says that I made some changes and cant switch without commit. It is not a good way to save files manually, then remove them, then change branch and paste modified files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you started working in branch `A`, made some changes, but then realized that you really should have been working in branch `B`.  Don't worry, `git stash` will come to the rescue to save you.

Just type `git stash` from the Bash prompt and the changes from your current working directory will be stashed away.  Note that Git also stashes your current stage, but I will assume that you have not yet staged anything.

Then, just switch to the `B` branch as you normally would:

```
git checkout B
```

And apply the stash:

```
git stash apply
```

Now if you type `git status`, you should see all the changes you made in the `A` branch.

If you then also want to commit this work, then `git add` the appropriate files and do a `git commit` into the `B` branch.

Note that there is another option here involving making a format commit in the `A` branch, then moving it later to the `B` branch, but that solution is more complex, and I would probably use `git stash` here.

Comment: No, i need this changes in branch B, not A. I'd like to save it in B

Comment: @IvanSalosin My answer saves in branch B, you didn't read it clearly.