# git - Switching to another branch before commit

Tags: git

I have a stable *master* branch, and began working on a *dev* branch.

Suppose in *dev* I change a few files, but then want to temporarily switch back to *master* -- in my case, to run the *master* code in a debugger to check some code blocks. Then, I'll switch back to *dev* to continue my work, but in the meantime, I'm not ready to `commit` *dev*.

In this case, I thought staging the *dev* files via `git add src/modified_files*` before `git checkout master` would do the trick. But when I compiled the *master* code, I found that I was mistaken (i.e. the modified files still existed, and were not swapped with the *master* files).

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: git stash. then switch to master. when you switch back to dev run stash pop

Comment: `git add` doesn't change your working tree. It prepares the next commit.

Comment: @JeffCharter Perfect. That worked. Suggest making it an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can safely commit your changes on `dev` then switch to `master`. When you switch back to `dev`, run `git reset HEAD~1` and Git restores the status of your repo as it is now. It's better than using a stash because a branch is always visible but a stash can be easily forgotten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git. How to save changes in wrong branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541356/git-how-to-save-changes-in-wrong-branch)

Comment: @phd That's not a duplicate. The answer happens to use the same git commands, but for an entirely different application.

Comment: Another method is simply clone the repository into a second directory, and run your other branch in there. I do that all the time for testing pull requests at work.

Answer (score 1):

**> git stash**

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working
>   directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts
>   the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

[git-stash documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

then, when you're ready to go back,

**> git stash pop**

> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top
>   of the current working tree state

[git-stash pop documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt)